Can't send from Gmail via a domain that I own that used to be managed by Google Workspace
The Background
I have a business domain that I manage via Namecheap at through which I have sent and received email for years. A while back I switched to managing email for this domain via Google Workspace. Now that I have ramped that business down, I have closed my Google Workspace account and have gone back to managing the email for this domain on my own.
The Problem
I use my personal Gmail to send a receive email from a few different domains. I have added them to my Gmail account through Settings > Accounts and Import > Check mail from other accounts, and also Settings > Accounts and Import > Send mail as.  I have attempted to manage email from the above-mentioned domain this way, and while I am able to receive emails from that domain, Gmail will not let me send through it. When I try, I get a message that I no longer own the domain. This is plainly false, but because I was managing it through Google Workspace for a time, and that account in now closed, Google seems to "think" that I no longer own the domain. Google's documentation is no help.
If you have experienced this issue, please chime in.
